# Using a function in place of sheet_name string in vlookup formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I'm duplicating and inventory worksheet every week, and then referencing the previous week's worksheet to update statistics. It was tedious to update the sheet_name strings in all of my formulas week after week, so I hoped to use a VBA function. Simple enough:

```
Function lastsheet() As String
  lastsheet = ActiveSheet.Next.Name
End Function
```

The function works, and upon recalculation returns the name of last week's sheet as a string just fine. However, when I use it in the following formula, Excel thinks the function is a string itself. It doesn't execute the function. The following formula takes last week's mean, and updates it with a new measurement.

```
=($AB3+VLOOKUP($A3,'lastsheet()'!$A$3:$AE$400,31,FALSE)*($AD3-1))/$AD3
```

Excel gives me an 'update values' window, and wants me to direct it to the sheet named "lastsheet()." I've tried all of the following in place of the sheet_name string:

```
lastsheet()
=lastsheet()
'lastsheet()'
'=lastsheet()'
```

Is there any way I can use some sort of variable in place of the explicit sheet_name string and get this formula to work?

Comment: Use the [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-ba22e49d-7d4e-4782-a48b-d4007d89477a?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) to construct the lookup array.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped. I had to figure out how to use the INDIRECT function, and got help here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/indirect.htm